# how to use "Users" feature in Azure Mobile Service .NET backend

Tags: .net, azure, oauth, azure-mobile-services

[here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/12/16/enhanced-users-feature-in-azure-mobile-services.aspx) describe how to use "Users" feature in Azure Mobile Service js backend

how to use this feature in .NET backend?

Comment: This is exactly what I need RIGHT NOW!!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the feature that you are talking about has just been announced in the latest Azure Mobile Services update.

Here is the announcement blog post - http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/02/custom-login-scopes-single-sign-on-new-asp-net-web-api-updates-to-the-azure-mobile-services-net-backend/ . I believe that "Custom Scopes for Social Authentication Providers" contains the information that you are looking for.

Hope this helps.